# Error configuring Terraform AWS Provider - Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

**[----------------------- UPDATE --------------------------]**

I have tried a tutorial to integrate terraform with s3 now. The S3 bucket is created and I have created an IAM user, and I am using its Access key and secret key.
Nonetheless I keep getting errors regarding the providers after `terraform init`:

**backend.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">=0.12.0"
  backend "s3" {
    region  = "us-east-1"
    key     = "terraform.tfstate"
    profile = "tu"
    bucket  = "terraformstatebucket3107"
  }
}
```

**config file in .aws folder**

```
[tu]
region = us-east-1
output = json
```

**credentials file in .aws folder**

```
[tu]
aws_access_key_id = AKIA*****************
aws_secret_access_key = nn3M1*****************
```

**Error:**

```
Initializing the backend...

Error: error configuring S3 Backend: no valid credential sources for S3 Backend found.

Please see https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/s3.html
for more information about providing credentials.

Error: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
    For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
```

Comment: Did you run `terraform init` prior to running apply?

Comment: @MarkoE  Yes, sure did

Comment: Are your AWS access key and secret access key by any chance in all caps in the credentials file?

Comment: I would agree that if the error message persists and you have set the creds in various locations, then they are probably malformed somehow.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I have updated the question with the credentials file content

Comment: @MarkoE Should they be?

Comment: As something else to try, drop the `profile = "default"` line

Comment: Can you just put your credentials inside the provider block and see if it's working? Have you already test it this way?

Comment: @vidura I have tried that but no luck

Comment: Are you able to access AWS resources with the AWS CLI? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-welcome.html

Comment: You provided your `~/.aws/config` file. What about `~/.aws/credentials`?

Comment: @Marcin I have updated my post and there are both files

Comment: Your profile in credentials have different structure then in AWS docs. It should be `[tu]`, not `[profile tu]`.

Comment: @Marcin Yes, nonetheless that is not what causing this issue though. i've changed it and ran `terraform init` again

Comment: Just to confirm..aws folder is in your home folder?

Comment: yes it is `/home/user/.aws`

Comment: @Marcin Found a solution, posted has a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I have tried every solution that was suggested here, but unfortunately none of them solved my issue.
After some digging, I found a solution that worked for me. That was executing the `terraform init` command with the `-backend-config` option like this:

```
terraform init -backend-config="access_key=<your access key>" -backend-config="secret_key=<your secret key>"
```

This is the question where I found this solution:
[Error while configuring Terraform S3 Backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449909/error-while-configuring-terraform-s3-backend?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you need to check.

1. There should be a file under **.aws** folder with name **credentials** and content of that file should be having access key and secret key.

   ```
   [tu]
   aws_access_key_id = ***************
   aws_secret_access_key = ************************
   ```
2. If the above file is present with correct keys, and still same error is coming then I will suggest you should mention access key and secret key in your provider block like this

   ```
    provider "aws" {
      access_key = var.aws_access_key
      secret_key = var.aws_secret_key
      region = var.region
    }
   ```

And store the above variables values in **.tfvars** file

```
aws_access_key ="****your access key****"
aws_secret_key = "***your secret key****"
```

Hope with these settings it should work and even after this issue persist, then I see in your .aws/config you have mentioned **mfa arn**.

If Multi-factor Authentication is enabled then try adding **mfa session token** in **backend.tf** file as well along with provider block that I have mentioned above

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">=0.12.0"
  backend "s3" {
    region  = "us-east-1"
    key     = "terraform.tfstate"
    bucket  = "terraformstatebucket3107"
    token   = "*****Your MFA SessionToken*****"
  }
}
```

To get the MFA SessionToken please check [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/authenticate-mfa-cli/)

Comment: I actually thought that with the MFA session token it would solve the problem. But I still get the same error...

Comment: Ahh I see, I just updated the backend.tf content in above answer, can you try removing "profile" parameter from backend "s3" block and use the mentioned provider settings as per 2nd point once. The problem I see is with your aws profile due to which s3 backend is not getting initailised if you try this way it should work..

Comment: Did not work, nonetheless, I found a solution for my problem and I posted it here. But I will give some credit for your answer since this might be useful for some people! Thank you @Arpan

Answer (score 0):

Do run `terraform init` you have to add `-backend-config` options for your credentials (aws keys).

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue when trying to run using Terraform Cloud as the backend store for state.

Make sure to either set the Environment variables in Terraform Cloud or to set the Execution Mode to "Local" so your local system is used.

I spent a while troubleshooting the profile not being found since I had set it to run "Remote" and everything else was actually correct.

[Screenshot of Terraform Cloud Execution Mode Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjpQc.png)