# error configuring S3 Backend: no valid credential sources for S3 Backend found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, circleci

I've been trying to add CI/CD pipeline `circleci` to my `AWS project` written in `Terraform`.
The problem is, `terraform init` `plan` `apply` works in my local machine, but it throws this error in CircleCI.
Error -

```
Initializing the backend...
╷
│ Error: error configuring S3 Backend: no valid credential sources for S3 Backend found.
│ 
│ Please see https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/s3.html
│ for more information about providing credentials.
│ 
│ Error: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
│   For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
```

My `circleCi config` is this -

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
  python: circleci/python@1.5.0
  # terraform: circleci/terraform@3.1.0

jobs:
  build: 
    #  will use a python 3.10.2 container
    docker:
      - image: cimg/python:3.10.2
    working_directory: ~/project
    steps:
      - checkout


      - run:
          name: Check pyton version
          command: python --version
          
      - run:
          name: get current dir
          command: pwd

      - run:
          name: list of things in that
          command: ls -a

      - run:
          name: Install terraform
          command: bash scripts/install_tf.sh

      - run:
          name: Init infrastructure
          command: bash scripts/init.sh dev



# Invoke jobs via workflows
workflows:
  .......
```

And my `init.sh` is -

```
cd ./Terraform
echo "arg: $1"

if [[ "$1" == "dev" || "$1" == "stage" || "$1" == "prod" ]]; 
    then
        echo "environement: $1"
        terraform init -migrate-state -backend-config=backend.$1.conf -var-file=terraform.$1.tfvars
    else
        echo "Wrong Argument"
        echo "Pass 'dev', 'stage' or 'prod' only."
fi
```

My `main.tf` is -

```
provider "aws" {
    profile = "${var.profile}"
    region = "${var.region}"
}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {

  }
}
```

And `backend.dev.conf is -

```
bucket = "bucket-name"
key    = "mystate.tfstate"
region = "ap-south-1"
profile = "dev"
```

Also, my `terraform.dev.tfvars` is -

```
region = "ap-south-1"
profile = "dev"
```

These work perfectly with in my local unix (mac m1), but throws error in `circleCI` for backend. Yes, I've added environment variables with my `aws_secret_access_key` and `aws_access_key_id`, still it doesn't work.
I've seen so many tutorials and nothing seems to solve this, **I don't want to write aws credentials in my code**. any idea how I can solve this?

**Update:**
I have updated my pipeline to this -

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
  python: circleci/python@1.5.0
  aws-cli: circleci/aws-cli@3.1.3

jobs:
  build: 
    #  will use a python 3.10.2 container
    docker:
      - image: cimg/python:3.10.2
    working_directory: ~/project

    # Checkout the code as the first step. This is a dedicated 
    steps:
      - checkout
  
      - run:
          name: Check pyton version
          command: python --version
          
      - run:
          name: get current dir
          command: pwd

      - run:
          name: list of things in that
          command: ls -a

  aws-cli-cred-setup:
    executor: aws-cli/default
    steps:
      - aws-cli/setup:
          aws-access-key-id: aws_access_key_id
          aws-secret-access-key: aws_secret_access_key
          aws-region: region
      
      - run:
          name: get aws acc info
          command: aws sts get-caller-identity

  terraform-setup:
    executor: aws-cli/default
    working_directory: ~/project
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Install terraform
          command: bash scripts/install_tf.sh
      
      - run:
          name: Init infrastructure
          command: bash scripts/init.sh dev
          context: terraform


# Invoke jobs via workflows
workflows:
  dev_workflow: 
    jobs:
      - build:
        filters:
          branches:
            only: main

      - aws-cli-cred-setup
        # context: aws
      
      - terraform-setup:
          requires:
            - aws-cli-cred-setup
```

But it still throws the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to fix this issue. You have to remove profile from `provider and other .tf files` files.
So my `main.tf` file is -

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "${var.region}"
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.30"
    }
  }
  backend "s3" {

  }
}
```

And `backend.dev.conf` is -

```
bucket = "bucket"
key    = "dev/xxx.tfstate"
region = "ap-south-1"
```

And most importantly, You have to put `acccess key`, `access key id` and `region` inside `circleci-> your project -> environment variable`,
And you have to setup AWS CLI on circleci, apparently inside a job `config.yml`-

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
  python: circleci/python@1.5.0
  aws-cli: circleci/aws-cli@3.1.3

jobs:
  build: 
    #  will use a python 3.10.2 container
    docker:
      - image: cimg/python:3.10.2
    working_directory: ~/project

plan-apply:
    executor: aws-cli/default
    docker:
      - image: docker.mirror.hashicorp.services/hashicorp/terraform:light
    working_directory: ~/project
    steps:
      - checkout

      - aws-cli/setup:
          aws-access-key-id: aws_access_key_id
          aws-secret-access-key: aws_secret_access_key
          aws-region: region

      - run:
          name: get aws acc info
          command: aws sts get-caller-identity
      
      - run:
          name: Init infrastructure
          command: sh scripts/init.sh dev

      - run:
          name: Plan infrastructure
          command: sh scripts/plan.sh dev

      - run:
          name: Apply infrastructure
          command: sh scripts/apply.sh dev
.....
.....
```

This solved the issue. But you have to init, plan and apply inside the job where you set up `aws cli`. I might be wrong to do setup and plan inside same job, but I'm learning now and this did the job. API changed and old tutorials don't work nowadays.
Comment me your suggestions if any.

Comment: Good that you managed to get it working! I hope my other post was helpful in solving this issue. I have seen a lot of people struggling with parameters inside their provider and backend blocks and then having this exact same error when they run it from a pipeline.

Comment: Actually the no posts ever mentioned what to include and what not to include inside a provider section, that's creating this issue. There's also API change related issues.

Answer (score 2):

You have probably added the `aws_secret_access_key` and `aws_access_key_id` to your project settings. But I don't see them being used in your pipeline configuration. You should do something like, so they are known during runtime:

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
  python: circleci/python@1.5.0

jobs:
  build: 
    docker:
      - image: cimg/python:3.10.2
    working_directory: ~/project
    environment:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Check python version
          command: python --version
      ...
```

I would advise you read about environment variables in the [documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/env-vars#setting-an-environment-variable-in-a-context).

Comment: Some tutorials showed that I can put my credentials in environment variable. You have a point. But how can I do that without hard coding my credentials in my repo? Seems like I still have to put them somewhere in my repo.

Comment: Tested, setup a cli but it still throws the same error.

Comment: I have done so, but terraform init does throw that exact same error.

Comment: I can see you tried a lot of stuff, so I would suggest you refactor / take out the good parts. Just do it as my example and it should work. Furthermore, I would recommend you read my post about the best practices: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73758453/7950592

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I managed to get it work, removed profile from variables and aws provider. 
There is an issue which I got stuck again, `init` and `plan` works only when I am in aws cli setup job, else it does not find aws as commands. Any idea?

Comment: You are out of scope there, in your case you don't have to use that job at all. Preferably stick to circleci/terraform@3.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a profile to your backend will fix this issue. Example:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.30"
    }
  }

  backend "s3" {
    bucket  = "terraform-state"
    region  = "ap-south-1"
    key     = "dev/xxx.tfstate"
    profile = "myAwsCliProfile"
  }
}
```